# Android Square gradient?

Tags: android, xml, gradient

Any idea how to draw square gradient using xml in android?

http://www.filterforge.com/wiki/index.php/Square_Gradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using shapes you can draw three kinds of gradient: the usual one-way gradient color, radial gradient (which is a circle of gradienting color) and sweep gradient. You can see examples [here](http://escomic.net/217) and [here](http://android.okhelp.cz/bitmap-canvas-color-gradient-linear-radial-sweep-rounded-corner-android-example/). However, I am almost convinced that none of these will serve your needs. I am not aware of any other way of providing gradient coloring in android.